# how to get the data from a component within a form in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a  with the following structure in react...

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Age</label>
        <input />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Gender</label>
        <input />
    </div>

    <AddressComponent />

    <button type='submit'>
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way for me to pass the AddressComponent data up to the parent form component onSubmit? The AddressComponent has a lot of state to manage and a load of functions and it appears a few more times across my website and so I don't want to keep repeating the same code over and over again.

Anyone know if there's a way for me to pass the AddressComponent state up to the parent form component onSubmit?

Comment: use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com), it handle forms very easy .

Comment: I think if you shared more of your code ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) is a good start), I'd have a better chance at answering your question. But for now, you can't pass data back to a parent component, that goes against the data flow of react; data only flows down. 

In your case, you could put all your logic in the parent component and pass it down via props, or use a global state management system. You could try React Context, Zustand, Redux. Quite a lot of options :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ref to get access to the child functions so:

```
const AddressComponent = ({}, ref) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getData: getData,
  }));

  const getData = () => {
      return data;
  }
  return <div></div>;
};

export default React.forwardRef(AddressComponent);
```

and you can get data in your parent and in submit like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const AddressRef = useRef(null);
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
       const data =  AddressRef.current.getData();
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Age</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Gender</label>
                <input />
            </div>

            <AddressComponent ref={AddressRef} />

            <button type='submit'>
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```